# Is there any way to copy file's content in clipboard without opening the file?

Tags: vim, clipboard

Always, I am using vim as my text editor. But, when I want to copy full file's content in clipboard to paste another place I open the file in gedit and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

Opening the file in text editor and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is overhead to me. Because I have to open the file in text editor, although I don't edit the file.

So, if there is any command that can copy the file's content in clipboard it better.
e.g.
`clip file.txt`

There also a possibility to gain this feature in vim by mapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to some command or make a `clip` command to copy. But, I don't know how to copy entire file in vim using command.

**N.B.** My vim doesn't support `+clipboard`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xclip will do what you want

`xclip -selection clipboard -i <file>`

note that `-selection clipboard` is only needed if you want the file in the clipboard (thats the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> one) if you omit it the files content will be put into the primary buffer (thats the one where you paste by clicking the mousewheel).

Comment: Error: Can't open display: (null)

Answer (score 1):

A few things you could try here.

1) From vim type in **gg"+yG** from normal mode, this will bring you to the top of the file, then paste all lines onto the clipboard.

2) You could try catting the file, highlighting it, then using ctrl-insert to copy the highlighted text.

3) As above, but right click on the top bar of the window and look for and Edit/Copy option.

Cheers,
Paul T

Comment: your solution works only inside vim, not for clipboard.

Comment: Wrong. The whole idea of "+ is to copy text ONTO THE CLIPBOARD! You can also use "* in place of "+.

Comment: Although My vim is in `-clipboard` features?

Comment: Then it won't work for your implementation of vim. Good luck in finding a solution that works for you!

Comment: Reading question carefully is better before posting a answer.

Comment: Personally there's nothing I hate more than an ungrateful question poster. Makes me question why I used up my own valuable time and effort in giving my best possible answer. I shall not be answering any more of your questions. By the way, careful reading of your question shows me that it's been flagged as  a duplicate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73466/discussion-between-paul-t-and-alhelal).